# Give the Laplace transform of the expression!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Given the equation $u_π(t)sin(at)$, where $u_τ(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. 
>   Give the Laplace transform $Y(s)$.

In order to use the formula $L\{u_c(t)\cdot f(t-c)\}=e^{-cs}\cdot F(s)$ I have to rewrite $sin(at)$, my idea was to write it as $-sin(at-\pi)$ but is not enough because I need inside the $sine$ $(t-\pi)$ and not $(at-\pi)$, how can I rewrite it in order to use the above formula? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: another variant of the transform law is

$$\mathcal{L}\{u_c(t)f(t)\}=e^{-cs}F(s+c)$$

which lets you do a shift after the transform instead of before. This way, you only need the transform of $\sin(at)$, rather than the function shifted.